# Export data from db2 with column names

Tags: db2, export-to-excel

I want to export data from db2 tables to csv format.I also need that first row should be all the column names.

I have little success by using the following comand

```
EXPORT TO "TEST.csv" 
OF DEL 
MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL coldel: ,
SELECT col1,'COL1',x'0A',col2,'COL2',x'0A' 
FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

But with this i get data like

```
Row1 Value:COL1:
Row1 Value:COL2:
Row2 Value:COL1:
Row2 Value:COL2:
```

etc.

I also tried the following query

```
EXPORT TO "TEST.csv" 
OF DEL 
MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL 
SELECT 'COL1',col1,'COL2',col2 
FROM ADMIN_EXPORT;
```

But this lists column name with each row data when opened with excel.

Is there a way i can get data in the format below

```
COL1   COL2
value  value
value  value
```

when opened in excel.

Thanks

Comment: Given that you're using this command, I'm assuming you're on LUW.  There's apparently an 'Export to Excel' utility - can you not use that?

Comment: I want to do it thru program code as there are many many tables.

Answer (score 8):

After days of searching I solved this problem that way:

```
 EXPORT TO ...
 SELECT 1 as id, 'COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT 2 as id, COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM myTable)
 ORDER BY id
```

You can't select a constant string in db2 from nothing, so you have to select from sysibm.sysdummy1.
To have the manually added columns in first row you have to add a pseudo-id and sort the UNION result by that id. Otherwise the header can be at the bottom of the resulting file.

Answer (score 1):

Quite old question, but I've encountered recently the a similar one realized this can be achieved much easier in 11.5 release with `EXTERNAL TABLE` feature, see the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57584730/11946299

Example:

```
$ db2 "create external table '/home/db2v115/staff.csv' 
using (delimiter ',' includeheader on) as select * from staff"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
$ head /home/db2v115/staff.csv | column -t -s ',' 
ID  NAME      DEPT  JOB    YEARS  SALARY    COMM
10  Sanders   20    Mgr    7      98357.50  
20  Pernal    20    Sales  8      78171.25  612.45
30  Marenghi  38    Mgr    5      77506.75  
40  O'Brien   38    Sales  6      78006.00  846.55
50  Hanes     15    Mgr    10     80659.80  
60  Quigley   38    Sales         66808.30  650.25
70  Rothman   15    Sales  7      76502.83  1152.00
80  James     20    Clerk         43504.60  128.20
90  Koonitz   42    Sales  6      38001.75  1386.70
```

Answer (score -1):

Insert the column names as the first row in your table.

Use order by to make sure that the row with the column names comes out first.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. How would you insert the column name as the first row for a column having data type INTEGER for example?