# export data from db2 from all tables in N schemas into CSV with column names

Tags: sql, bash, shell, csv, db2

I'm trying to export a bunch of DB2 tables to CSV, with column names. I don't see any straight forward way to do this. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122505/export-data-from-db2-with-column-names) to get the data I want. But I have to execute that over hundreds of tables. Is there a way to dynamically get all the columns and tables given N schema names?

I also tried [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204790/how-to-systematically-export-all-tables-from-a-db2-database-schema-to-csv#204802) which exports all tables to csv in a schema but this doesn't give me column names. So if someone could show me show to change this script to get column names in the CSVs my work is done.

The server is running: Red Hat Linux Server.

Comment: @user281989 Do you have an ability to use DB2 Command Line Processor on the client? If yes, then what’s the OS on your client (or server, if you have an access to the server’s command line)?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I can run Command Line Processor. Looking for a script for the same. Server is running on RedHat. Made this edit in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using files

The following db2 command generates the export script:

```
export to exp.sql of del modified by nochardel
select
  x'0a'||'export to file_header of del modified by nochardel VALUES '''||columns||''''
||x'0a'||'export to file_data of del messages messages.msg select '||columns||' from '||tabname_full
||x'0a'||'! cat file_header file_data > '||tabname_full||'.csv'
from
(
select rtrim(c.tabschema)||'.'||c.tabname as tabname_full, listagg(c.colname, ', ') as columns
from syscat.tables t
join syscat.columns c on c.tabschema=t.tabschema and c.tabname=t.tabname
where t.tabschema='SYSIBM' and t.type='T'
group by c.tabschema, c.tabname
--fetch first 10 row only
)
;
```

It's better to place the command above to some file like `gen_exp.sql` and run it to produce the export script:

```
db2 -tf gen_exp.sql
```

The export script `exp.sql` consists of 3 commands for each table:
* db2 `export` command to get a comma separated list of columns
* db2 `export` command to get table data
* concatenation command to collect both outputs above to a single file

You run this script as follows:

```
db2 -vf exp.sql -z exp.sql.log
```

## Using pipe

gen_exp_sh.sql:

```
export to exp.sh of del modified by nochardel
select
  x'0a'||'echo "'||columns||'" > '||filename
||x'0a'||'db2 "export to pipe_data of del messages messages.msg select '||columns||' from '||tabname_full||'" >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &'
||x'0a'||'cat pipe_data >> '||filename
from
(
select
  rtrim(c.tabschema)||'.'||c.tabname as tabname_full
, rtrim(c.tabschema)||'.'||c.tabname||'.csv' as filename
, listagg(c.colname, ', ') as columns
from syscat.tables t
join syscat.columns c on c.tabschema=t.tabschema and c.tabname=t.tabname
where t.tabschema='SYSIBM' and t.type='T'
group by c.tabschema, c.tabname
--fetch first 10 row only
)
;
```

Run it as follows:

```
db2 -tf gen_exp_sh.sql
```

The export shell script `exp.sh` consists of 3 commands for each table:
* echo command to write a comma separated list of columns to a file
* db2 export command to get table data **to a pipe** (started in a background)
* simple `cat` command to read from the pipe and add data to the same file with the columns list

Usage:
You must create the pipe first and source (`dot space script` notation - it's important) the export script afterwards:

```
mkfifo pipe_data
db2 connect to mydb ...
. ./exp.sh
rm -f pipe_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this great tool: https://www.sql-workbench.eu/. It's universal and you may transfer data between any type of database motors.