# How to include column headers also with the export result in IBM DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400, db2-luw

I was trying to export data from table in DB2 using command..I m abo to export into csv file..But column headers are not there..Need to have column headers as well.So what I can add in the sql query to get column headers as well

Comment: Show us your current export command!

Comment: I run select query. In db2, there is option to export the result set,We just need to provide the output folfer and file name..It will be get export to that file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export data from db2 with column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122505/export-data-from-db2-with-column-names)

Comment: which platform?  you have both db2-400 and db2-luw...they are different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [export data from db2 from all tables in N schemas into CSV with column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691654/export-data-from-db2-from-all-tables-in-n-schemas-into-csv-with-column-names)

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in the latest (2019) Db2 11.5 release and Db2 Warehouse (local and on Cloud) with [`EXTERNAL TABLE`](http://%20https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.licensing.doc/doc/c0058536.html) feature via `INCLUDEHEADER`/`COLUMN_NAMES` switch, see an example

```
$ db2 "create external table '/home/db2v115/staff.csv' using (delimiter ',' includeheader on) as select * from staff"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
$ head /home/db2v115/staff.csv | column -t -s ',' 
ID  NAME      DEPT  JOB    YEARS  SALARY    COMM
10  Sanders   20    Mgr    7      98357.50  
20  Pernal    20    Sales  8      78171.25  612.45
30  Marenghi  38    Mgr    5      77506.75  
40  O'Brien   38    Sales  6      78006.00  846.55
50  Hanes     15    Mgr    10     80659.80  
60  Quigley   38    Sales         66808.30  650.25
70  Rothman   15    Sales  7      76502.83  1152.00
80  James     20    Clerk         43504.60  128.20
90  Koonitz   42    Sales  6      38001.75  1386.70
```